# Abandoning std::future if the underlying thread was killed

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm building plugins for a host application using C++11/14, for now targeting Windows and MacOS.  The plugins start up async worker threads when the host app starts us up, and if they're still running when the host shuts the plugins down they get signaled to stop.  Some of these worker threads are started with `std::async` so I can use an `std::future` to get the thread result back, while other less involved threads are just `std::thread`s which I ultimately just `join` to see when they're done.  It all works nicely this way.

Unless the host decides not to call our shutdown procedure when it shuts down itself...  Yeah, I know, but it really is that bad sometimes -- it often enough just crashes during shutdown.  And they even plan to make that into a 'feature' and call it "Fast Exit" to please their users; just pull the plug and we're done extra fast :(

For that case I have registered an `std::atexit` handler.  It last-minute signals any still running threads to exit NOW (atomic bools and/or signals to wake them up), then it waits a second to give the threads some time to respond, and finally it detaches the regular std::thread threads and hopes for the best.  This way at least the threads get a heads up to quickly write intermediate state to disk for a next round (if needed), and quit writing to probably already deceased data structures, thus avoiding crashes which would make any crash dump point the finger at my plugins.

However, atexit handlers run at OS DLL unload time, so I'm not even allowed to use thread synchronization (right?).  And under the debugger I just saw all of the worker threads were presumably already killed by the OS, since the atexit handler's thread was the only thread left under the debugger.  Needless to say, all remaining std::futures went into full blocking mode, hanging up the remaining corpse of the dead host app...

Is there a way to abandon an std::future?  In MS Visual C++ I saw futures have an `_Abandon` method, but that's too platform specific (and undocumented) for my taste.  Or is my only recourse to not use std::future, do all thread communication via my own data structures and synchronization, and work with simple std::threads which can just be detached?

Comment: I sure hope your software isn't controlling hardware... "fast shutdown" could be a disaster then. And regrettably no I don't know another solution then to implement collaborative termination like you do (with a signal). I would keep pushing on finding the root cause of the shutdown mechanism not triggering instead of having to patch up a system like that (so sorry not much help, but I feel your pain)

Comment: It looks like you could use a singleton global object that cleans everything when it's destructor is called. I mean: the destructor **has** to be called at some point.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: no; we're not into medical imaging nor running in nuclear installations :)

Comment: @ichramm: Good call! And I already have such a global static `Daemon` class :) That's the one setting up the atexit handler and shutting down other subsystems with their threads (logging module, error state management, etc.).

Comment: @ichramm: For bonus points: destruction of globals is done by the default atexit handler, but the destruction order of global objects is the reverse of their construction order, so if you just have a bunch of global objects, you cannot reliably have one of them panic-mode clean up the others (they might already be gone -- Static Order Initialization Fiasco). But if you make all singletons lazy-initialized, and have Daemon's constructor call on all other singletons too, Daemon is the last to be fully constructed and thus the first to get deconstructed.

Comment: Phew ;) Well long time ago my first architect told me "to die gracefully is an art" (netjes doodgaan is ook een kunst). Just brainstorming, sometimes it helps to turn the box inside out... instead of having the threads check for a finish condition, why not let the exit handler wait on the threads.  e.g. have a mutex/condition_variable/threads_in_use count and let you're exit handler (or static global) wait for the count to go to zero? (Make an instance of a RAII object on each thread, that will increase count on creation, decreases on exit). Assuming the rootcause cannot be found ofc.